# Proper DataGrid search from TextBox in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, search, mvvm, datagrid

I am new to the MVVM pattern, and a little confused on when to use Code Behind.  I have a very simple form right now, that includes one TextBox, and one DataGrid.  What I would like is to be able to have the DataGrid change its selected item based on the TextBox.

I have done this in Code Behind and it works fine using the following code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string cellContent = dtReferral.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        try
        {
            if (cellContent != null && cellContent.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length).Equals(textBox1.Text))
            {
                object item = dataGrid1.Items[i];
                dataGrid1.SelectedItem = item;
                dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(item);
                //row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                break;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Now, I just want to highlight the Item in the Datagrid that starts with text in textbox, and allow the user to press a button to edit selected item.

Is it okay to have this logic in the Code Behind file? Or would I need to do this through some sort of binding?  If I should do this through the View Model with Binding, any direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you only want to highlight the cells with the text from the `TextBox` you could make an `AttatchedProperty` for the `DataGrid` to accept your search value from the `TextBox` and create another `AttatchedProperty` for the `Cell` to indicate a match that you can usee to set properties in the `Cell` style. Then we create a `IMultiValueConverter` to check the `Cell` value for a match to the search `Text`.

This way its reusable on other projects as you only need the `AttachedProperties` and `Converter`

Bind the `AttachedProperty` `SearchValue` to your `TextBox` `Text` property.

```
 <DataGrid local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Then create a `Style` for `DataGridCell` and create a Setter for the `AttachedProperty` `IsTextMatch` using the `IMultiValueConverter` to return if the cells text matches the `SearchValue`

```
<Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Then we can use the `Cells` attached `IsTextMatch` property to set a highlight using a `Trigger`

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

### Here is a working example showing my rambilings :)

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication17
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                TestData.Add(new TestClass { MyProperty = GetRandomText(), MyProperty2 = GetRandomText(), MyProperty3 = GetRandomText() });
            }
        }

        private string GetRandomText()
        {
            return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName());
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TestClass> _testData = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<TestClass> TestData
        {
            get { return _testData; }
            set { _testData = value; }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    }

    public static class DataGridTextSearch
    {
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SearchValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SearchValue", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridTextSearch),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public static string GetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(SearchValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsTextMatch.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextMatch", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridTextSearch), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public class SearchValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string cellText = values[0] == null ? string.Empty : values[0].ToString();
            string searchText = values[1] as string;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText))
            {
                return cellText.ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.ToLower());
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication17.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication17"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">

    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Name="SearchBox" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="grid" local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

### Edit:

If you just want to select the row based on a single Column you can modify quite easily :).

Override the Style of `DataGridRow` instead of `DataGridCell`.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
```

First pass in the property you want into the `IMultiValueConverter` this should be your `DataContext`

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext.MyProperty" />
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Then change the `Trigger` to set `IsSelected` on the `Row`

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Should look like this:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grid" local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext.MyProperty" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the work you have done on this.  Honestly all I want to do is select the entire row based on the text in the first column.  Could I adapt your code for that.

Comment: I have added an edit that shows how to modify to do what you need, its pretty easy to change :)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks for this answer . That's why I love this site. We get so many things to try ourselves.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 would it be possible to scroll the searched item into the view

Comment: I cant fit the answer here but if you sak as a new question I can show you how :)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 please find the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474971/how-can-i-scroll-the-searched-item-into-the-view-of-gridview-in-wpf

Comment: +1 @sa_ddam213 I have implemented your code above, but the `SearchValueConverter` `Convert` method is only being fired when I load data into the grid, not when the value of the text box is changed. Any ideas? Thanks for this post - it was most helpful :]

Comment: @sa_ddam213 your search works fantastic, I used your first highlighted cell style. I have created a popup with the search textbox in it and added one more binding to the converter in the same fashion as SearchValue, however this is causing me issues, I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927740/how-to-fix-binding-on-datagridcell and was hoping you may be able to shed some light on it.

Comment: Hi, the code is working perfect!

What if I like to re-populate the DataGrid base on the text that the user encoded in the search textbox rather than highlighting or selecting the record in the datagrid using MVVM pattern? I can re populate the datagrid  using code behind but not sure on how to implement it in MVVM pattern.

TIA!

Comment: What if I want to highlight only the word I'm searching?

Comment: WpfApplication17 made me laugh.  You must answer a lot of these questions.  So Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using MVVM for quite a while now, and I still prefer using it as a guideline rather than a strict practice, partly because it isn't always practical to do everything in MVVM pattern exactly, and even more so if you are not too familiar with it.
I would suggest just playing around with it until you manage to find a form of MVVM that suits you. 
I don't believe it is taboo to have Code in the Code Behind of the MVVM if the code is UI related.
 ScrollIntoView isn't a Bindable property so if you want to bind to it you will have to create a dependency Property to indirectly handle the binding. As for setting the selected item you could do it through something like:

View:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Text={Binding Path=Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,147,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected}" >
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
 private string _selected = "";
 public string Selected
 {
      get{ return _selected; }
      set
      {
            if(_selected == value) return;
            _selected = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
      }
 }
```