# How can I scroll the searched item into the view of GridView in Wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As a reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-serach-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm) question I want to know how can I scroll the searched item into the view of grid view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `AttachedProperty` to keep track of the `SelectedTtem` and Scroll it into view if needed.

```
   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AutoScrollToSelectedRow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollToSelectedRowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScrollToSelectedRow", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridTextSearch)
        , new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnAutoScrollToSelectedRowChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoScrollToSelectedRow(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoScrollToSelectedRowProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoScrollToSelectedRow(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoScrollToSelectedRowProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnAutoScrollToSelectedRowChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datagrid = s as DataGrid;
        if (datagrid != null)
        {
            datagrid.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
            datagrid.EnableRowVirtualization = !((bool)e.NewValue);
            datagrid.SelectionChanged += (g, a) =>
            {
                if (datagrid.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    datagrid.ScrollIntoView(datagrid.SelectedItem);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
 <DataGrid local:DataGridTextSearch.AutoScrollToSelectedRow="True"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also tried something like this only but I am not sure why this is not working at my end