# Datagrid text search

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to search a text in the datagrid, A code written like below gives error

```
For i As Integer = 0 To _dt.Items.Count - 1
            Dim row As DataGridRow = DirectCast(_dt.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i), DataGridRow)
            For j As Integer = 0 To _dt.Columns.Count - 1
                If row IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim cellContent As TextBlock = TryCast(_dt.Columns(j).GetCellContent(row), TextBlock)
                    If cellContent IsNot Nothing AndAlso cellContent.Text.Equals(txtfind.Text) Then
                        _dt.ScrollIntoView(row, _dt.Columns(j))
                        Dim presenter As DataGridCellsPresenter = GetVisualChild(Of DataGridCellsPresenter(row))
                        Dim cell As DataGridCell = DirectCast(presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(j), DataGridCell)
                        _dt.SelectedItem = cell
                        cell.IsSelected = True
                        row.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.[Next]))
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Error is for row : Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers. 
Statement: `Dim presenter As DataGridCellsPresenter = GetVisualChild(Of DataGridCellsPresenter(row))`

Help appreciated
abhimoh

Comment: There is a C# example here, should be pretty easy to convert to VB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-search-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm/15469031#15469031

Comment: Yes I want to close this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
   Dim presenter As DataGridCellsPresenter = GetVisualChild(Of DataGridCellsPresenter(row))

'you have created an array with row number of values.
```

to:

```
   Dim presenter As DataGridCellsPresenter = GetVisualChild(Of DataGridCellsPresenter)(row)
```