# Getting an error in searching data from dataGrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, search, datagrid, textbox

I have tried to search in a `dataGrid` using the following XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext.MyProperty" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-search-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm)

But it gives me an error that `DataGrid` is not defined. So I changed `<DataGrid>` to `<my:DataGrid>`

Now it gives me the following error on line no 1 :
The attachable property SearchValue was not found in type DataGridTextSearch.

And Another Error on Line no. 3 :
The type local:SearchValueConverter was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.

The XAML of my window looks like :

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="532" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="29" Margin="104,22,147,0" Name="txt" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoWordSelection="True" />
        <my:DataGrid x:Name="grid" local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
            <my:DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext.MyProperty" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </my:DataGrid.Resources>
        </my:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have messed up with namespaces, references and (i guess) Resharper.
First of all - no need to specify namespace for DataGrid - it is standard control, so if it is not recognized - possibly you really miss some assemblies in your project's references.

Then - check your namespace - I guess that x:Class="Window1" is wrong, because usually there is project namespace prefix there.

Third, before using any namespace, including "local", you need to define it first, like xmlns:local="clr-namespace:your namespace goes here", so local:DataGridTextSearch and similar expressions won't work before you do so.

And finally, build your solution before proceeding to fixing XAML warnings - usually, if you did everything right, they vanish after build.

What I recommend - create a new empty WPF Application project, copy there ALL the code (including codebehind) from the post you mentioned and check if your problems persist.