# Change the Colour of a TextBox BorderBrush Upon Text Match MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers

All, I have created a `DataGrid` with a search box above it. When the user types and the text is loacted in the `DataGrid` the back colour of the matching cells are coloured orange. I have managed this, but now (retro-spectively) want to change the search `TextBox`'s `BorderBrush` to 'Red' if the text is *not* found (and default otherwise). The XAML for the control is

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceStudio.Views.ResourceControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:dataAccess="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.DataAccess" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
   <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="searchBox" BorderBrush="#FF007ACC" BorderThickness="2">
         <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                  </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </TextBox.Resources>
      </TextBox>
      <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
         <Border>
            <controls:ResourceDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}" 
                      dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=searchBox, 
                      Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
               <controls:ResourceDataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyIndex" Binding="{Binding KeyIndex}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="FileName" Binding="{Binding FileName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResourceName" Binding="{Binding ResourceName}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                  <controls:CollectionTextColumn Collection="ResourceStringList" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
               </controls:ResourceDataGrid.Columns>
               <controls:ResourceDataGrid.Resources>
                  <dataAccess:SearchValueConverter x:Key="searchValueConverter"/>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                     <Setter Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchValueConverter}">
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                           </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
               </controls:ResourceDataGrid.Resources>
            </controls:ResourceDataGrid>
         </Border>
      </Grid>
   </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Where my basic `Trigger` for the `TextBox` does nothing. **How can I change the colour of the `TextBox` `BorderBrush` using the same mechanism as I use for the `DataGrid`?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. The class that governs the `DependencyProperty` and the `IConverter` is*

```
public static class DataGridTextSearch 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SearchValue", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridTextSearch),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static string GetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SearchValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextMatch", typeof(bool), 
          typeof(DataGridTextSearch), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value);
    }
}

public class SearchValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string cellText = values[0] == null ? String.Empty : values[0].ToString();
        string searchText = values[1] as String;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText))
        {
            return cellText.ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.ToLower());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be a bit of a tricky one if you are using Virtualization in your `DataGrid`, the problem is that the `IsTextMatch` property is registered to the individual `Cells` in the `DataGrid` not a global instance, to change the `TextBox` if the text is not found, you will need to iterate all the `Cells` in the `DataGrid` and check if any have the attached property set, And if you have virtualization set you will have to render all the items to check if its a match.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an EventSetter on the cells to set a public bool value in your View to set if the `TextBox` border should be red or not, since this is all view related the event won't break the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a way to do this by creating a new `AttachedProperty` `IsAnyTextMatch` for the `DataGrid`

In the `IMultiValueConverter` we pass in the `DataGrid` and set the new `DataGrid` `IsAnyTextMatch`  property to true if any match is found, and if you type in the `SearchBox` the `IsAnyTextMatch`will be reset to false

Now you can create a `DataTrigger` on the TextBox and set it to the `DataGrid` `IsAnyTextMatch` to set the TextBox border color.

This may not be the most glamorous way to do this but it does not require you to iterate over the `DataGrid` collection again just to set the `TextBox` background.

Here is the example based off my answer here: [Proper DataGrid search from TextBox in WPF using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-search-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm/15469031#15469031)

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public IEnumerable<TestClass> TestData
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestClass { Column1 = "Stack", Column2 = "Overflow" };
                yield return new TestClass { Column1 = "Is", Column2 = "An" };
                yield return new TestClass { Column1 = "Awesome", Column2 = "Resource" };
            }
        }
    }


    public static class DataGridTextSearch
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SearchValue", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridTextSearch),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChangedCallback)));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is DataGrid)
            {
                // serach text has changed, reset tag to false
                (d as DataGrid).SetValue(IsAnyTextMatchProperty, false);
            }
        }

        public static string GetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(SearchValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextMatch", typeof(bool),
              typeof(DataGridTextSearch), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAnyTextMatchProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAnyTextMatch", typeof(bool),
           typeof(DataGridTextSearch), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public static bool GetIsAnyTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsAnyTextMatchProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsAnyTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsAnyTextMatchProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public class SearchValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string cellText = values[0] == null ? String.Empty : values[0].ToString();
            string searchText = values[1] as String;
            var datagrid = values[2] as DataGrid;
            bool returnvalue = false;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText))
            {
                returnvalue = cellText.ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.ToLower());
            }

            // we found a match so mark DataGrid tag to true for use on TextBox
            if (returnvalue)
            {
                datagrid.SetValue(DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatchProperty, true);
            }
            return returnvalue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="188" Width="288" Name="UI" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10">

    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBox Name="SearchBox" BorderThickness="3" >
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (local:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch), ElementName=dataGrid}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
                  local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  local:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                                <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" />
                                <!-- pass in datarid-->
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Absolute quality. Thanks very much for your time, it is much appreciated. I am learning WPF in my spare time and to be honest I am struggling a bit... All the best.

Comment: I have implemented the above mirroring what you have but I can't get it to work. I understand your approach and it clearly works for you. Would you be kind enough to take a look at my solution? Sorry to be so cheeky here. I understand if you are too busy and if you think this rude I apologise. All the best, and again thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know what `controls:ResourceDataGrid` is so I cant test with your code.

Comment: I will update the question with the resource grid, or I can upload the entire solution which may be an easier way to go? That is of course if you would still be so kind... Thanks again.

Comment: In the `PropertyChangedCallback` of the `SearchValue` dependency property I am checking for DataGrid, try replacing dataGrid with you custom control Type, tha could be whats stopping it. An also the converter is using DataGrid not ResourceDataGrid, Just a guess really

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have already changed these to suit. Everything is firing correctly. I can't for the life of me work out what is going wrong - it is likely to be something basic. If you wouldn't mind, can you take a look at the project? It can be downloaded from http://sdrv.ms/12aLLIc

Comment: I think I had the same issue when I made this example. In the TextBox trigger try changing `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch, ElementName=dataGrid}" Value="false">` to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (dataAccess:DataGridTextSearch.IsAnyTextMatch), ElementName=dataGrid}" Value="false">` 
like I have above, I added the `( )`in your solution and it works :)

Comment: So basically what I think happened is the WPF binding engine got a bit confused and bound to the global instance of IsAnyTextMatch not to the DataGrids instance (<-- total guess ), That could be a StackOverflow question in itself, I also would like to know the answer