# WPF DataGrid - "Ctrl-F" type Functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm still a beginner with regards to C# and WPF, and I am unable to find an answer to my question.

I have a WPF datagrid this is displayed in a readonly mode  and would like to be able to have the user use `Ctrl-F` to find a cell value in the datagrid. Is this or some variant of possible, or do I need to create a search box as a control and take things from there?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(Scathing comments are also welcome!)

I am currently using 2010 Express. The datagrid is defined below.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1"   Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" 
              BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
              SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True"
              Width="1395" />
```

Comment: I am building the same thing right now, what was your final approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know a build in search but maybe this'll help you: [DataGrid search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-search-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm)

A nice approach to build a textsearch (including highlighting).

//edit

You can use InputBindings and e.g. open a search window from your viewmodel.

```
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="L" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: while my intent was to find a way to use "Cntl-F" or something like it, your link does provide a nice intro for using a text search box.  If there are no other suggestions, I may to go that route.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Maybe InputBindings will help you. I'm not pretty sure if they work on a read only DataGrid.

Comment: Nergal - I actually had the chance today to follow the link you provided in your first post and go through the suggested code. It solves about 95% of my problem, so I am going to go ahead and mark this as closed.  Plus I got to learn something new, not too shabby.  Thanks again.