# WPF DataGrid Cells Being Randomly Highlighted When Passed Through A Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am attempting to highlight all the cells that start with a given value in a text box that the user enters. I have looked at several examples, generated the following code, that works, sort of, till you start scrolling vertically.

First we have the XAML, which utilizes a multi-binding:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CellColor}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}"/>
                    <Binding Mode="OneWay" ElementName="contactFilterTextBox" Path="Text"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Next the class that I created, which inherits from the IMultiValueConverter class:

```
public class ColorBasedOnFilterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush cellColor = Brushes.White;
        DataGridCell cellToAnalyze = (DataGridCell)values[0];
        TextBlock cellContents = (TextBlock)cellToAnalyze.Content;
        if (cellContents != null)
        {
            string cellValue = (string)cellContents.Text;
            string filterValue = values[1].ToString();
            if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue)))
            {
                if (cellValue.ToUpper().StartsWith(filterValue.ToUpper()))
                {
                    cellColor = Brushes.LightSalmon;
                }
            }
        }
        return cellColor;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Initially, it works as I would expect as shown below:[image: Appropriate color classification by filter.]

The question then is when I scroll, values that are obviously are selected as shown in the image below?[image: Inappropriate color classification by filter.]

I am very new to WPF, and surely I am doing something wrong, but I am baffled as to what it is. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default **`Virtualizing`** is on for dataGrid which means container i.e. DataGridRow will be generated for only visible items.

Also default value of **`VirtualizationMode`** is **`Recycling`** which means when you scroll, cells which have moved out of focus will be used to host new visible items that's why you see incorrect item to be coloured because it might have used same row.

To overcome this you can ***set VirtualizationMode to Standard*** so that always new rows will be generated to host new visible items.

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
   .......
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction. The issue now is that the binding for the text box value only works the first time the converter is run. As in, the highlighting works for the shown grid, but as soon as it comes to another row that requires highlighting, the function fails with the error: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'. If I look at the value that is assigned in the values array of the converter arguments it is "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" Do I need to register a dependency property for this, and if so, how?

Comment: Problem lies within your converter here - `string filterValue = (string)values[1];`. Replace it to this - `string filterValue = values[1].ToString();`. `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` signifies that bound value is not set. You should always check for this value in converter before blindly converting value.

Comment: Sorry that was really unclear on my part. I should do a logical test to determine if the value is set. In this case I know that the bound value is not set, but I don't understand why. The first time the converter goes through the visible cells, the filter value is set and it highlights as it should, however when the converter is run again (say after scrolling), it no longer is (with no modification to the entry in the text box). That is the part I don't understand.

Comment: `ElementName` in binding find element traversing Visual Tree. So both controls should be attached to Visual tree but when you scroll the grid, items which are not in view will be destroyed by dataGrid owing to Virtualization. So, second binding is passed as Unset value because textBox couldn't be found because cell is no more part of Visual tree. Also, if you see error comes for the very first cell. Just do ToString() since anyhow you are no interested in items which are out of view. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: So, now to your original question. Is it solved now or looking for something else?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The filter box is still visible, so why would it not be part of the visual tree? The only thing that is scrolling is the content inside the grid box.

Comment: Style is applied on DataGridCell and binding is on cell. But since Cell is not in visual tree. How will it get upto textBox via elementName?

Comment: @BBQSingular - Does that answer your queries?

Comment: It's the opposite of what you describe. The textbox value is used to filter the grid, not the other way around. As such, the textbox is always visible meaning it will always be in the visual tree, right?

Comment: @BBqSingular - I am not getting it, this is never a part of the question. This was already an issue in your code for which too I have provided an answer. However, let me explain third time. TextBox is always in visual tree but not dataGrid cell and from cell style you asked to find textBox element. For ElementName to work both elements have to be in visual tree but since cell is not that's why its unable to locate it.

Comment: I finally understand, sorry. I misread your earlier post, and as a result was confused about the point you were trying to make. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my (admittedly very limited) experience, changing the properties of a DataGridCell in the CodeBehind often goes amiss due to RowVirtualization. I avoid it like the plague when possible. Changing the background color of a cell would be a good example of something that falls into that category.

An alternative (arguably better) option would be to not set the color in the CodeBehind at all, and instead use a DependencyProperty to determine if the cell matches the criteria, and then set the background color (or whatever) using a Trigger. You can get a fuller idea of what I'm talking about from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469031/1943542) and a little more possibly useful info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33185028/1943542) to a question I asked recently, especially if you're looking to "find" all of the cells that *would* be highlighted if they weren't otherwise virtualized. And here's a code excerpt with a very similar goal to the original question to get you started (mostly it's just code adapted from the provided links) in case it helps somebody sometime.

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<DataGrid.Resources>
<local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

The DependencyProperty:

```
Public NotInheritable Class DataGridTextSearch
Private Sub New()
End Sub
Public Shared ReadOnly SearchValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SearchValue", GetType(String), GetType(DataGridTextSearch), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.[Inherits]))
Public Shared Function GetSearchValue(obj As DependencyObject) As String
    Return DirectCast(obj.GetValue(SearchValueProperty), String)
End Function
Public Shared Sub SetSearchValue(obj As DependencyObject, value As String)
    obj.SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value)
End Sub
Public Shared ReadOnly IsTextMatchProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextMatch", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataGridTextSearch), New UIPropertyMetadata(False))
Public Shared Function GetIsTextMatch(obj As DependencyObject) As Boolean
    Return CBool(obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty))
End Function
Public Shared Sub SetIsTextMatch(obj As DependencyObject, value As Boolean)
    obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value)
End Sub
End Class
```

And the converter (This could definitely stand to be fleshed out, but you get the idea):

```
Public Class SearchValueConverter
Implements IMultiValueConverter
Public Function Convert(values() As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IMultiValueConverter.Convert
    Dim cellText As String = If(values(0) Is Nothing, String.Empty, values(0).ToString())
    Dim searchText As String = TryCast(values(1), String)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText) Then
        If cellText.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()) Then
            Return True 
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function
Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes() As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
```