# Add counter to search text in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

sa_ddam213 wrote an excellent reply on how to [highlight cells in a datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467553/proper-datagrid-search-from-textbox-in-wpf-using-mvvm). I would like to have a counter indicating the number of cells with the found text but haven't found a way to do it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you forgot to tag `MVVM`? Because your code-behind approach (check cells for match and count matches) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Count = 0;    

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    string cellContent = dtReferral.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    try
    {
        if (cellContent != null && cellContent.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length).Equals(textBox1.Text))
        {
            Count++;
            object item = dataGrid1.Items[i];
            dataGrid1.SelectedItem = item;
            dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(item);
            //row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            break;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

}

This should get the count.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The fact that the searched text has been found using attached properties and the value converter isn't this repeating the search? I was wondering if could use the them for the count.